# Null columns in data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am creating a data frame from a json file in HDFS for e.g `hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/sparkApp/finalTxtTweets/-1606454440000.txt/part-00000`  in scala spark shell. I have created a schema as I only need the id and text part of the json file with `val schema = new StructType().add("UserID", StringType, true).add("Text", StringType, true)` and with the schema, I create the data frame with this:

`val df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/sparkApp/finalTxtTweets/-1606454440000.txt/part-00000")`

However, it returns a data frame of 2 columns (UserID and Text) but with null as rows.

This is what the json file from part-00000 is like

`JObject(List((UserID,JInt(2308359613)), (Text,JString(RT @ONEEsports: The ONE Esports MPL Invitational is now live!  Join us as 20 of the best teams from Indonesia, Singapore, Malaysia, Myanmar…))))`

Anyone have any idea of how to correctly parse the json file? Or is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: That is not a json string, it is a string representation of a JObject.

Comment: oo okie thanks @EmiCareOfCell44